# How to get function's min/max on spesific interval with apache-common-maths

Tags: java, apache-commons-math

I can't find any word about looking for function extrema (max/min) in [apache-commons-math userguide](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/).

How to find function min/max with help of apache-commons-math?

P.S. At least for polynomial function

Answer (score -1):

A quick and easy approach would be to have your function as the cost function, pick one of the optimization routines that takes bounds, use those bounds to restrict your search range. Then optimize